# Symfony2 porting to Windows application

Tags: php, symfony, webserver, desktop-application

Is there any way to porting a Symfony2 App to a .exe Desktop app ?

I've tried tideSDK but without any success maybe for the complexity of the symfony2 framework.
I would not use xampp or similar but if there is no alternative I will use a portable apache server (like goserver or xampp etc..)

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved with **mongoose** web server, php-cgi, nsis and **webkit** library.
I've modified just a bit mongoose and the app.php symfony2 entry point file because mongoose not read .htaccess file.
Then using **nsis** I've made a single .exe installer

Thanks

Comment: Please can you give some detail on how you process to resolve the problem with .htaccess, because I'm in the same case as you, I tried phpdesktop which uses mongoose, but I have problems with .htaccess

Comment: You can pass rewrite rules as options to mongoose. 
mongoose -url_rewrites **=web/index.php

Answer (score -1):

If your project is a command-line-application:

Have you thought about packing your application into a `.phar` application?
You could then easily access it with `$ php yourpackage.phar <command>`.
If you then work with the `PATH`, you may be able to simply write `$ yourpackage <command>`.

If your project has a web interface, you would need to include a web browser and webserver w. php interpreter into the exe (im no expert in such programming languages), thats not very convenient, is it?